# How to Import and use functions in groovy

Tags: groovy, import

This is for a plugin so I am bound to restrictions.

When I have a file `MyClass.groovy` that contains `class MyClass {}`. I can Import that using a statement `import MyClass`.

My problem starts when I need to import a function only. I have a file `File.groovy` that contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call()
{
}
```

Adding the statement `import File` to my code does compile. 
I can not tell how to write a client function that can call `call()`,

Answer (score 0):

`import File` creates a wrapping class named `File`.

`def test = new File()` gives an instance with all methods.

`test.call()` calls the desired method.